# How can I use an access token obtained from the Microsoft Graph API to access other APIs

Tags: azure, exchangewebservices, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

My team and I built Web App that uses the Microsoft Graph API to recover data from a user's Office 365 environment. The application uses Azure AD to provide users with an access token.

We're now trying to add a component that can access the same user's Exchange Online informations using the EWS Api. However, it seems like trying to use the same access token as the one provided by the Graph API always returns a 401 (Unauthorized) response even if I have to proper permissions set on my Azure AD Application. Here is the code we use to try and access some user's information:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.HttpHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
service.PreAuthenticate = true;
service.SendClientLatencies = true;
service.EnableScpLookup = false;
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
TasksFolder tasksfolder = TasksFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Tasks,
                         new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.TotalCount));
```

The Bind method will always return a 401 error which prompts me to think that ther access token from one API is not valid for another one.

If that's the case, is it possible to get a single access token that will be valid for mutiple API calls ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I cant see a permission worded exactly like the first answer suggests in Azure app permissions

Answer (score 0):

It should work okay but EWS doesn't support the constrained permissions model like REST so " EWS applications require the "Full access to user's mailbox" permission. as per the note in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761(v=exchg.150).aspx